# Crash when trying to load C++/CLI wrapper dll

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am trying to use a C++/CLI wrapper dll from a C# application. It started out by giving AccessViolationExceptions so I tried to debug. I tried mixed mode, native only and almost all the options suggested online. I still get an exception when (presumably) the dll is loaded. The stack trace looks like this (When debugging the dll as native only).

```
>   ntdll.dll!RtlPcToFileHeader()  Unknown
    msvcr110_clr0400.dll!_CxxThrowException()  Unknown
    clr.dll!string "d:\\iso_whid\\amd64fre\\base\\ntos\\r"...()    Unknown
    msvcr110_clr0400.dll!_CallSettingFrame()   Unknown
    msvcr110_clr0400.dll!__CxxCallCatchBlock() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RcFrameConsolidation()   Unknown
    clr.dll!MethodDesc::MakeJitWorker(class COR_ILMETHOD_DECODER *,unsigned long)   Unknown
    clr.dll!MethodDesc::DoPrestub(class MethodTable *)  Unknown
    clr.dll!PreStubWorker()    Unknown
    clr.dll!ThePreStub()   Unknown
    000007fe8351011b()  Unknown
    clr.dll!CallDescrWorkerInternal()  Unknown
    clr.dll!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler(struct CallDescrData *,int)  Unknown
    clr.dll!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker(unsigned __int64 const *)  Unknown
    clr.dll!RunMain(class MethodDesc *,short,int *,class PtrArray * *)  Unknown
    clr.dll!Assembly::ExecuteMainMethod(class PtrArray * *) Unknown
    clr.dll!SystemDomain::ExecuteMainMethod(struct HINSTANCE__ *,unsigned short *)  Unknown
    clr.dll!ExecuteEXE(struct HINSTANCE__ *)    Unknown
    clr.dll!_CorExeMainInternal()  Unknown
    clr.dll!_CorExeMain()  Unknown
    mscoreei.dll!_CorExeMain() Unknown
    mscoree.dll!_CorExeMain_Exported() Unknown
    kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk() Unknown
    ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart() Unknown
```

Any idea about how to proceed is appreciated.

Comment: Have you got code for the C# wrapper?  Perhaps the wrapper is working fine and you're getting an access violation running the C++ code, what is it doing?  Is it accessing resources with DACLs on it?

Comment: The C++/CLI wrapper wraps some classes in a native C++ static library. The native code itself is pretty harmless. The problem is, I can't even get into debugging the native code let alone the wrapper. The wrapper itself fails to load.

Comment: The stack trace is too poor to have a guess.  Just make sure it doesn't get that far, Debug + Exceptions, tick the Thrown checkboxes so the debugger stops when the exception is thrown.  The kind of problem you have to look for is initializers in your native C++ code corrupting the process to a point that jitting code can't work anymore.  Comment stuff out to get somewhere.